# TSQL BULK INSERT: Populate Column With Source FileName

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I am looking for a better way to try to solve this problem as my current solution is very time consuming and inefficient.

I have a number of text files that all contain 1 column.

I use BULK INSERT to load that information into a SQL table, but I would like to be able to tell from which file the data was loaded and populate that into a column.

The existing workflow is to create a series of BULK INSERT and UPDATE statements in a text editor and then run them one after the other as below:

**Existing Workflow**

```
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP(MYDATA VARCHAR(MAX), FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX))

    BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\MYFILE_1.TXT' WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\FORMATFILE.FRM')

    UPDATE #TEMP SET FILENAME = 'MYFILE_1.TXT' WHERE FILENAME IS NULL

    BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\MYFILE_2.TXT' WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\FORMATFILE.FRM')

    UPDATE #TEMP SET FILENAME = 'MYFILE_2.TXT' WHERE FILENAME IS NULL

    BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\MYFILE_3.TXT' WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\FORMATFILE.FRM')

    UPDATE #TEMP SET FILENAME = 'MYFILE_3.TXT' WHERE FILENAME IS NULL
```

This is a terrible workflow and gets slower and slower the more rows are inserted into the table.

Does anyone have a way to do this at the time of doing the BULK INSERT or at least in a more efficient way?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you considered using SSIS for a job like this?  When you have more complicated workflow etc, the benefits of using SSIS become more apparent.

Comment: Thanks for your response @WindsofChange.  No, I have not looked into the SSIS route.  Are you able to give me a rough workflow on how this would be achieved and then I will go and do my own research?  Thanks

Comment: SSIS is an ETL (Extraction, Transform, Load) tool.  It allows you to develop a procedure to Load and Transform the data you're loading.  For example, you can load in your datasource (either passed in as a parameter, or you could loop through a folder and load everything there).  You could Transform the loaded data to include a hard-coded value (such as the datasource file location) in a column you then use to bulk insert into your table.
It's more involved than just writing a SQL script, but it's flexibility is far greater for ETL work that benefits from actual procedures.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  I will see if this is an option in our environment.

Answer (score 0):

As with most issues, I am sure there are MANY valid ways to do this.  However, I would do this dynamically by declaring the filename a variable, and then inserting the filename in the bulk insert.
This could get a bit complicated, and could very well be done using a Cursor Loop.

Another option would be to add a column to the txt files of which equals the file name.  I am sure this could be scripted via powershell etc..

I know my answer is vague, let me know if you want a few examples

Comment: Thanks for your response @E. Monk.  I will take a look into the variable option.  Unfortunately I cannot modify the original text files as they are in a specific structure.